# Openshift Gear performance, IOWAIT

Tags: openshift

I've been getting more and more DNS errors on my application (scaled django python).  So in an effort to see what is going on, i started to look at simple performance.

I started with the top command, and noticed the other day, the system load around 35+, and the IOWAIT remaining over 80%.

I thought it might be my application, so I run ctl_app stop and ran the same commands as above - SAME RESULTS, the gear is running very busy even without my app running.

With my application stopped, I ran iostat 5 to see if the same behavior was there, and it was!

My question is, without paying for a dedicated gear, is there any way to move to a less busy gear?

Thanks

J

Comment: What gear size are you on?

Comment: Small, Bronze plan.  However this just recently got much much worse, to the point im seeing 30-40 alerts a day out of django.

Comment: You could switch over to a Small.highcpu gear, but if you're just running on a free Small gear I wouldn't worry too much about it. OpenShift gears share CPU with other gears on the node, but your gear will always get a minimum fair share of CPU so you shouldn't run into any issues.

Comment: It turns out it wasn't a IOWAIT or CPU issue at all, but something broken on DNS with the node i was on.  Red Hat moved my gear, and viola, all my issues went away. strange.

Answer (score 1):

**Preface:**
What luciddreamz is correct. Each gear on OpenShift will always get its fair share of CPU (and other resources) on the node and that switching to a larger gear size will improve your application's performance.

To expand a bit.

OpenShift gears are essentially a combination of [SElinux and CGroups](https://www.openshift.com/products/architecture). The CGroups portion is what gives it it's "size" and you can run something like

`for i in $(oo-cgroup-read all);do echo “oo-cgroup-read $i” && oo-cgroup-read $i; done`

in the gear to see what the cgroup parameters are set at. If you take a look at your `oo-cgroup-read blkio.weight` it should be 500, thus proving what luciddreamz said about equal access.